# invoking constructor in java

Tags: java, object, constructor, superclass

```
class A {

    A() {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
     B() {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
 C() {
        System.out.print("C");
    }
}

public class My extends C {
My(){
super();
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        My m = new My();
    }
}
```

Question starts from one Interview Question **(what happens when an object is created in Java?)**

and answer is...

> The constructor for the most derived class is invoked. **The first
>   thing a constructor does is call the consctructor for its
>   superclasses**. This process continues until the constrcutor for
>   java.lang.Object is called, as java.lang.Object is the base class for
>   all objects in java. Before the body of the constructor is executed,
>   all instance variable initializers and initialization blocks are
>   executed. Then the body of the constructor is executed. **Thus, the
>   constructor for the base class completes first and constructor for the
>   most derived class completes last.**

So, according to above statement, answer should be **ABCC**, but it showing only **ABC**. Although, when i'm commenting the `super()` in derived constructor. Then, output is **ABC**.  Please, help me to figure out, did i misunderstand the above paragraph. ?

Comment: The output should be `ABC` (you're only creating a single instance) and that's exactly what I see when I run your code.

Comment: It should print `ABC`.  You may want to add a `System.out.println();` to the end of your `main` to be sure it's not just an artefact of your terminal.

Comment: It does print ABC to me as well, both with and without the super(). And why do you think you should have two C's?

Comment: I would expect **ABC** personally, because `super()` is implicitly called in each constructor (and therefore the call to `super()` in MyClass's constructor doesn't actually invoke the constructor again).  And indeed, upon testing, I get the result **ABC**.

Comment: Sorry !! for that, it was mistakenly typed. It was ABC. So, my question is why not ABCC ??

Comment: Again... why would you think that the constructor for C (or ANY constructor) should be called twice?

Comment: the `super()` that you add calls the parent constructor but it replaces the default `super()` call. You will never call the super constructor twice.

Comment: ok got it!! which means..we can call, atleast and atmost super constructor once only, either implicitly or explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the answer is **ABC**

```
My m = new My();
```

The above **first** invokes `My` class, then a super call is made to its super class i.e., `C` class, then a super call to `B` class is made, then a super call to `A` Class, then a Super call to `java.lang.Object` as all objects extend `java.lang.Object`.

Thus the answer is **ABC**.

You don't really need to **explicitly** call `super()` in your `My` class as it'd be included by the **compiler** unless you call an overloaded constructor of that class like `this(something)`.

Comment: You have to call `super()` for each and every child class of the super class constructor, please refer my above code for that.

Comment: @Bhavik: no, you're wrong. Please go back to the [Java school banks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Comment: @BhavikAmbani super() is included by the compiler unless you call an overloaded constructor using this() by default . you can ignore those super calls as they are included by the compiler . :)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR Updated my post, now revert the downvotes changes please

Answer (score -3):

The below code will print `ABC`

To invoke the constructor of the super class, the compiler will implicitly call the `super()` in each and every class extending the class, if you are not calling the `super` construcotr explicitly.

Comment: Wrong, if the first thing in a constructor is not either `this(...)` or `super(...)` then Java inserts an implicit `super()` call to the no-argument superclass constructor.

Comment: No, you must have to call super constructor explicitly for the class extending the parent class.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani nah, read my answer for detailed explanation :)

Comment: No, this is a fundamental part of Java - the language spec absolutely guarantees that every constructor will call either another constructor of the same class or a constructor of the superclass.  If you don't put in an explicit call the compiler will insert one for you.